# New theme (Astra) installed but home slider not working properly

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, theme, slider

website installed with new magento theme but slider not working proper how to check it and solve it. I have no idea how to edit slider statics blocks.

Comment: which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this javascript code to initialise slider :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#slider-elastic.elastic').eislideshow({
        easing    : 'easeOutExpo',
        titleeasing : 'easeOutExpo',
        titlespeed  : 1200,
        autoplay  : true,
        slideshow_interval : 3000,
        speed       : 800,
        animation   : 'sides'
    });
});
```

Comment: add code in the slider blocks ??

Comment: I dont know what `slider blocks` is ? But yes, you can add it to `CMS > Home Page`. In short, this code must be available any where in  home page .

Comment: You can add this code at last in this JS file : `/skin/frontend/rwd/astrabootstrap/js/common.js`

Comment: if you are adding it to HTML, wrap this code by `<script>` tag

Comment: thnks sir its working now but slider change through click can its run auto ??

Comment: slider showing and change with clicks ... it can change with auto ... ??

Comment: plz CHECK, I've UPDATED my answer. Have you updated the code in `common.js`. ??????  I already informed you in above comment.

Comment: yes sit it's updated but autoplay  : true, show syntax erorr in this line

Comment: You missed a COMMA `,`  after `titlespeed  : 1200` . . plz plz double check.

Comment: yes sir it's working fine thankyou sir Anil Suthar